# Work around for StoryQ report generation broken after introduction of Nunit3.0

Tags: nunit-3.0, storyq

First let me say the I tried in the StoryQ forum but there is no much activity there and I feel I wont get any answer there.

This is the issue, after introduction of Nunit 3.0 the **StoryQ** report generation is broken

After introduction on Nunit 3.0 the way to find where your application is running has changed, it used to be that:
    **Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()** 
was good enough, but now you are forced to use:
    **NUnit.Framework.TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory**

The thing about using **GetCurrentDirectory** is that now with Nunit 3.0 gives you something like **C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW**.

I suspect that StoryQ is using **GetCurrentDirectory** and is getting a **UnauthorizedAccessException** becuase is trying to create a folder in the windows folder mentioned above.

Is there a way I could force StoryQ to use the correct directory without me going into the code of StoryQ and change it?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it seems to work:

```
   Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(NUnit.Framework.TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory);
```

Now StoryQ goes to the right directory to create his report.